# MATLAB loading data from multiple .mat files

Tags: matlab

My data is x,y co-ordinates in multiple files

```
a=dir('*.mat')
b={a(:).name}
```

to load the filenames in a cell array

How do I use a loop to sequentially load one column of data from each file into consecutive rows of a new/separate array......?

I've been doing it individually using e.g.

```
Load(example1.mat)
A(:,1)=AB(:,1)
Load(example2.mat)
A(:,2)=AB(:,1)
Load(example3.mat)
A(:,3)=AB(:,1)
```

Obviously very primitive and time consuming!!

My Matlab skills are weak so any advice gratefully received

Cheers

Many thanks again, I'm still figuring out how to read the code but I used it like this;
    a=dir('*.mat'); 
    b={a(:).name}; 
    test1=zeros(numel(b),1765); 
    for k=1:numel(b) S=load(b{k});
I then used the following code to create a PCA cluster plot
    test1(k,:)=S.AB(:,2); end [wcoeff,score,latent,tsquared,explained] =  pca(test1,... 'VariableWeights','variance'); 
    c3 = wcoeff(:,1:3) coefforth = inv(diag(std(test1)))*wcoeff; I = c3'*c3 cscores = zscore(test1)*coefforth; 
    figure() plot(score(:,1),score(:,2),'+') xlabel('1st Principal Component') ylabel('2nd Principal Component') –

I was using 'gname' to label the points on the cluster plot but found that the point were simply labelled from 1 to the number of rows in the array.....I was going to ask you about this but I found out simply through trial and error if I used 'gname(b)' this labels the points with the .names listed in b.....

However the clusterplot starts to look very busy/messy once I have labelled quite a few points so now I am wondering is is possible to extract the filenames into a list by dragging round or selecting a few points, I think it is possible as I have read a few related topics.....but any tips/advice around gname or labelled/extracting labels from clusterplots would be greatly appreciated. Apologies again for my formatting I'm still getting used to this website!!!

Comment: Hi Stephen. I saw that you proposed an edit to my answer; but it will likely be rejected by the system as an"attempt to reply". Can you edit your original question instead? Thanks!

Comment: I seem to have deleted some of the original question!! Really struggling with this website to be honest!!

Comment: haha no problem! I'll take a look a bit later today and edit your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it. Hopefully I got what you wanted correctly :)

The code is commented but please ask any questions if something is unclear.

```
a=dir('*.mat');
b={a(:).name};

%// Initialize the output array. Here SomeNumber depends on the size of your data in AB.
A = zeros(numel(b),SomeNumber);

%// Loop through each 'example.mat' file
for k = 1:numel(b)

%// ===========  
%// Here you could do either of the following:

1)
   %// Create a name to load with sprintf. It does not require a or b.
   NameToLoad = sprintf('example%i.mat',k);

   %// Load the data
   S = load(NameToLoad);


2) 
   %// Load directly from b:
   S = load(b{k});
   %// ===========

%// Now S is a structure containing every variable from the exampleX.mat file. 
%// You can access the data using dot notation.

 %// Store the data into rows of A
   A(k,:) = S.AB(:,1);

end
```

Hope that is what you meant!

Comment: Many thanks, I'm still figuring out how to read the code but I used it like this; a=dir('*.mat');
b={a(:).name};

test1=zeros(numel(b),1765);
for k=1:numel(b)
    
    S=load(b{k});
    test1(k,:)=S.AB(:,2);
end


[wcoeff,score,latent,tsquared,explained] = pca(test1,...
'VariableWeights','variance');

c3 = wcoeff(:,1:3)

coefforth = inv(diag(std(test1)))*wcoeff;

I = c3'*c3

cscores = zscore(test1)*coefforth;

figure()
plot(score(:,1),score(:,2),'+')
xlabel('1st Principal Component')
ylabel('2nd Principal Component')

Comment: I'm using gname to display the cluster plot label but any idea how to link this to the actual filename in 'a' or 'b' Sorry about the formatting of this question!!

Comment: oh sorry I just saw this comment! Can you add the information in your original question (by editing it) please? thanks!